# How do I test my localhost WordPress project with VirtualBoxVM?

Tags: urls, localhost, wp-head, paths, ip

I'm working on a WordPress project set up with MAMP on localhost. I try testing the site on internet explorer with VirtualBoxVM by browsing to my local ip. 
My problem is, wp_head() outputs absolute path's to css and js resources, so the VirtualBoxVM Browser tries to load http://localhost:[port]/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-[xy]/style.css?ver=3.5 which will, of course, fail.

How do I get VirtualBoxVM to load these resources properly?

Maybe I can make the resource urls relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, don't use 'localhost'. That only works if you are testing from the same machine that is running the server. (A virtualized machine counts as a different machine.) Give your server (the machine running the server) a static IP address-- something like 192.168.1.5-- and use that instead of 'localhost'. That will work for any machine on your subnet.